# Time limit exceeded error. Word Ladder leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, queue, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve leetcode problem(https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/description/):

Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from beginWord to endWord, such that:

Only one letter can be changed at a time.
Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that beginWord is not a transformed word.
Note:

Return 0 if there is no such transformation sequence.
All words have the same length.
All words contain only lowercase alphabetic characters.
You may assume no duplicates in the word list.
You may assume beginWord and endWord are non-empty and are not the same.

Input:

> beginWord = "hit",
>       endWord = "cog",
>       wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]

Output:

> 5

Explanation:

> As one shortest transformation is "hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" ->
>   "cog", return its length 5.

```
import queue
class Solution:
    def isadjacent(self,a, b):
        count = 0
        n = len(a)

        for i in range(n):
            if a[i] != b[i]:
                count += 1
            if count > 1:
                return False

        if count == 1:
            return True

    def ladderLength(self,beginWord, endWord, wordList):

        word_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
        word_queue.put((beginWord,1))

        while word_queue.qsize() > 0:  
            queue_last = word_queue.get()
            index = 0

            while index != len(wordList):
                if self.isadjacent(queue_last[0],wordList[index]):
                    new_len = queue_last[1]+1
                    if wordList[index] == endWord:
                        return new_len
                    word_queue.put((wordList[index],new_len))
                    wordList.pop(index)
                    index-=1

                index+=1
        return 0
```

Can someone suggest how to optimise it and prevent the error!

Comment: I would do search from begin-word and also from the end-word and test if they "meet in the middle" at some level.

Comment: For reference this is equivalent to computing [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) for which there exists dynamic programming solutions. Please also post in plain English the algorithm you are trying to implement.  We can compare this to the code you've posted and help better.

Comment: dont revisit words you have already visited

Comment: @juvian OP does not: visited words are removed from `wordList`

Comment: @yeputons if wordList is a list, pop by index is too expensive

Comment: @AndyG: It’s not edit distance: it can be larger than the length of the string, as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to find the adjacent words faster.  Instead of considering every word in the list (even one that has already been filtered by word length), construct each possible neighbor string and check whether it is in the dictionary.  To make *those* lookups fast, make sure the word list is stored in something like a `set` that supports fast membership tests.

To go even faster, you could store two sorted word lists, one sorted by the *reverse* of each word.  Then look for possibilities involving changing a letter in the first half in the reversed list and for the latter half in the normal list.  All the existing neighbors can then be found without making any non-word strings.  This can even be extended to *n* lists, each sorted by omitting one letter from all the words.